# Parse a JSON string to a custom class

Tags: android, json

In an app that I'm developing I receive from a web-service a JSON string, I'm trying to covert this string into a custom class like:

```
public class User {
public String userID;
public String description;
public int PIN;

public User(){}
}
```

whith it's getter and setter method.

I've tried to do that stuff using a Gson and the method:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(String fromServer, User.class);
```

where the String "fromServer" it's already codified in JSON

if i print the String fromServer in a TextView i have an output like

```
[{"userId":"admin","description":"administrator","PIN":"00001"}]
```

but when i call

```
user.getUserId();
```

I got a NullPointerException and I don't Know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is returning an array of Users. Try using Gson like this:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>() {}.getType();
List<User> users = gson.fromJson(fromServer, listType);
User user = users.get(0);
```

Comment: Also, below comment about case sensitivity is correct and you should update your User model to ensure the values in the json match the field names in your Java class

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity. `userID` in java and `userId` in json.

Comment: This isn't the problem because if I create a new User, then i parse it to JSON with gson.toJson(user) and back to User.class and finally I call getUserId() it works and I got the Id without exception

Comment: I'm sure that works. `gson.toJson(user)` would return a json string where the property is `userID` with a capital `D`. (As opposite to the json string above with a lowercase `d`)

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is correct. You can verify this by creating User class using [Json2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and then using Gson to convert the json to class. Your User class should look like:

```
public class User {

private String userId;
private String description;
private String PIN;

public String getUserId() {
return userId;
}


public void setUserId(String userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}


public String getDescription() {
return description;
}


public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getPIN() {
return PIN;
}

public void setPIN(String PIN) {
this.PIN = PIN;
}

}
```

Now you can use Gson to convert json to User.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User user = gson.fromJson(fromServer, User.class)
```